# How can I monitor AWS S3 access by user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a number of IAM AWS users and I would like to:

1. See when and how much data each user is accessing.
2. Limit the amount of monthly data each user can read (to keep costs under control)

Is there a way to do that from within AWS?

The scenario I am trying to avoid here is having one user spam AWS S3 requests in a tight loop and generating a huge bill. I would like to be able to block access for that one particular user before they can rack up too huge a bill.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Can you please expand upon what you are wanting to achieve? First, what is an "AWS user" in your case? Is it somebody who has IAM credentials, or is it a user of an application hosted in AWS? If you are wanting to reduce costs, then are you referring to Data Transfer charges out to the Internet? If so, then your calculations would need to separate traffic _within_ AWS (eg between an EC2 instance and an S3 bucket) vs traffic going out to the Internet. So, is there a specific cost on your AWS bill that you are wanting to reduce? You can edit your question to add more detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way of monitoring IAM Users data usage in AWS. One (complex) approach to have some monitoring of this kind if you are using only S3 would be:

1. Implement AWS CloudTrail for auditing
2. Use CloudTrail logs to monitor user activity, such as GetObject requests to S3
3. Implement functions to get the S3 object size and multiply by the number of get requests of each user
4. Implement alarms related to that consumption per user

Its neither a simple nor an efficient approach, but there is no direct way of doing so in AWS.

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid that was the case. I think this means I also have to implement my own cost calculations (as that is what I ultimately care about)